# Can you search tfs history to find a file version which has specific code in it?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I'm trying to find some code which was added, then removed from a file.

I know the file was checked into TFS for at least a little while, but going through every version of the file will take longer then it needs to.

Is there anyway to search tfs history for a version of the file containing specific text?

Answer (score 2):

Speaking with the ObjectSharp TFS Guru he suggested (via[Twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/dlloyd/status/127405956773593088)):

> You could try [TFS Sidekicks or "tfpt searchcs"](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tfsidekicks/archive/2006/11/07/Better-search-and-history-add_2D00_in-for-Source-Control-Explorer.aspx) might do it.

Comment: The twitter link works, but your later Microsoft link is 404'ing.

Comment: tfpt searchcs searches only the metadata, not the source code itself. You might find what you are looking for in the check-in comment but otherwise you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could import the TFS repository into git and then use the "git pickaxe" (git log -S) to search all commit data in the repository.

There are several available tools, but this one looks good:
https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs#readme

And then read up on git pickaxe, which is what people call the "-S" option to "git log":  https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs#readme